# Apache: Override Accept-Language

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers, encoding

I have Chinese clients that provide the following in their http request headers:

```
Accept-Language: zh-cn,zh;q=0.5
```

This is causing problems with characters being dropped by our load balancer. Is there any way for Apache to rewrite those headers or to override the Accept-Language as:

```
Accept-Language: en,zh-cn,zh;q=0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can rewrite Client headers (not with the mod_xxx I know of) - but you can tailor the URL that's being sent with mod_rewrite - see [this page](http://tech-blog.borychowski.com/index.php/2009/03/htaccess/redirect-according-to-browser-language-mod-rewrite-and-http_accept_language/), for instance.

Comment: Thanks, but ideally I'd like to only use one URL. The problem is that if the user provides 'zh-cn' as the language the response contains Chinese characters that cannot be handled by the load balancer. For some reason if the user specifies 'en' these characters are automatically converted/dropped. Ideally the application developers should handle those foreign characters, but currently that isn't an option, so I'd like to force Apache to sanitise the response.

Comment: Uhm. Language negotiation and error handling should allow you to send pretty much any file as response - including one that does not contain chinese characters. That's broken, but so appears to be the load balancer :-)